# How don't clear UIView when I draw?

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawing, cgcontext

I'm drawing a line on UIView. When I call -setNeedsDisplay, my view becomes clear and drawing new line. How to continue current line? And how drawing with animation? Thanks.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    [super drawRect:rect];
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [_color CGColor]);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 10.0);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, _startPointX, 0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, _endPointX, 0);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

setNeedsDisplay totally redraw view. So you need to store all drawings somewhere and apply it every redraw.
What do you mean under animating drawing? Animating drawing is drawing itself. Just redraw the view after every small change and it will looks like you draw naturally.

Comment: Hi, I understand that setNeedsDisplay method redraw the wholview. But I can not get current context, other than drawRect method ? Is it true ?

Comment: Yes, you can't get current UIView context out of drawRect. You can only create new one with such methods like UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions.

Comment: Ohk, actually I am drawing in scrollview, and everytime drawing appends. as you said setNeedsDisply method redraws. I am finiding another way to draw, other than CGContext and drawRect. Thanks for that.

Comment: Probably BezierPath and custom method to draw.

Answer (score 0):

For animation, you can create a CAShapeLayer with these lines.

Then create a CABasicAnimation with keypath @"storkeEnd"
toValue set @1 to draw all your lines from clear to drawn down.